# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow (install matplotlib in VScode)

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm starting to run jupyter on VScode.
And trying to install matplotlib.. but i get the following error.

```
!pip install matplotlib
...
...
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

How can i solve this problem?? I need somebody help,,,

Comment: Please can you post the full traceback error?

Comment: Can you tell which pip and python version you are using. Did you update pip first?

Comment: How do you install `matplotlib`? If you use the command directly on the terminal `pip install pillow` to install `pillow`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a virtual environment, use `pip install matplotlib` to install `matplotlib` in the end of the active environment.

[image]

In addition, you can install `pillow` manually (`pip install pillow`), and then install `matplotlib`.